# RS232 communication between HMI and PC using Java

Tags: java, serial-port

I am trying to establish a communication between a PC (Windows) and Digital Weighing Scale Monitoring Module by RS232 communication cable. I am targeting to store the data from that module into a database using java. I am confident about the database part but I am not good yet in reading or writing data over a COM1 or COM2 port. Since javax.comm is not available currently, give me some reference for the available alternatives so that I can study and learn from a reliable source.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it finally by JSSC library. It is simple and user friendly